# PDF Box file not compatible with Fax machine

Tags: pdfbox, fax, rightfax

I am using apache pdf box api (java)for generating pdf's from pre-defined template(Created from Open office). Now when i try sending that pdf to fax machine(Rightfax server), its printing with Dots in it. Also if I change fonts nothing is printed except some dots in it.

Kindly advice whether there is any settings to be done in template creation to be compatible with fax format.

Regards,
Niteesh

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the PDF document was produced in color or greyscale.  Fax is strictly black & white.  The dots that you're seeing are a result of the dithering process, when the color or greyscale document is converted to black & white.